# MongoDB limit number of document to cycle?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm **not** trying to limit the number of results. I'm trying to find a way to only cycle N documents of the collection, when using

```
 collection->find([]);
```

Is there an option or flag for that? Using PHP Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [$sample](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) is what you are looking for.

It will randomly select **N** documents from the collection:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([ 
  { $sample: { size: 10 } } 
])
```